Imbalance Between Generator and Discriminator Losses in GAN Training for Super-Resolution
I am training a Generative Adversarial Network (GAN) for the task of image super-resolution. However, I am encountering a persistent issue where the generator's loss decreases significantly over time, but the discriminator's loss remains high and does not show any signs of improvement. This imbalance in training progress is preventing the discriminator from effectively distinguishing between real and generated high-resolution images.
I have attempted several strategies to address this problem, including:

Adjusting Learning Rates: I have experimented with different learning rates for both the generator and the discriminator to balance their training dynamics.
Gradient Clipping: To stabilize the training process, I have implemented gradient clipping to prevent exploding gradients.
Architecture Changes: I have modified the architectures of both the generator and the discriminator to ensure they are suitably matched for the task.

Despite these efforts, the issue remains unresolved. The generator continues to improve, producing higher quality images, while the discriminator struggles to provide meaningful feedback. Additionally, even when the discriminator loss comes close to zero, the evaluation metrics (PSNR and SSIM) do not improve, indicating that the quality of the generated images does not get better.
Here are some outputs and relevant sections of my training code:
Training Epoch 0 : 100%
 613/613 [05:26<00:00,  2.01it/s, disc_loss=0.296, gen_loss=0.0254]

Epoch [1/25]
Training - Generator Loss: 0.0254, Discriminator Loss: 0.2961

Testing Epoch 0 : 100%
 17/17 [00:05<00:00,  4.03it/s, disc_loss=0.000957, gen_loss=0.0227]

Testing - Generator Loss: 0.0227, Discriminator Loss: 0.0010
Average PSNR: 17.1919, Average SSIM: 0.6984
--------------------

Training Epoch 1 : 100%
 613/613 [05:26<00:00,  2.01it/s, disc_loss=0.00754, gen_loss=0.0235]

Epoch [2/25]
Training - Generator Loss: 0.0235, Discriminator Loss: 0.0075

Testing Epoch 1 : 100%
 17/17 [00:05<00:00,  2.99it/s, disc_loss=0.000166, gen_loss=0.0234]

Testing - Generator Loss: 0.0234, Discriminator Loss: 0.0002
Average PSNR: 17.2508, Average SSIM: 0.6964
--------------------

Training Epoch 2 : 100%
 613/613 [05:26<00:00,  2.01it/s, disc_loss=0.000411, gen_loss=0.0239]

Epoch [3/25]
Training - Generator Loss: 0.0239, Discriminator Loss: 0.0004

Testing Epoch 2 : 100%
 17/17 [00:06<00:00,  3.02it/s, disc_loss=9.79e-5, gen_loss=0.024]

Testing - Generator Loss: 0.0240, Discriminator Loss: 0.0001
Average PSNR: 17.1470, Average SSIM: 0.6932
--------------------

Training Epoch 3 : 100%
 613/613 [05:25<00:00,  2.01it/s, disc_loss=0.00344, gen_loss=0.0242]

Epoch [4/25]
Training - Generator Loss: 0.0242, Discriminator Loss: 0.0034

Testing Epoch 3 : 100%
 17/17 [00:05<00:00,  3.44it/s, disc_loss=0.000359, gen_loss=0.0252]

Testing - Generator Loss: 0.0252, Discriminator Loss: 0.0004
Average PSNR: 16.9989, Average SSIM: 0.6288
--------------------

Training Epoch 4 : 100%
 613/613 [05:26<00:00,  2.01it/s, disc_loss=0.00264, gen_loss=0.0242]

Epoch [5/25]
Training - Generator Loss: 0.0242, Discriminator Loss: 0.0026

Testing Epoch 4 : 100%
 17/17 [00:05<00:00,  4.10it/s, disc_loss=0.000105, gen_loss=0.0245]

Testing - Generator Loss: 0.0245, Discriminator Loss: 0.0001
Average PSNR: 17.1144, Average SSIM: 0.6622   

Training Code:
class FeatureExtractor(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(FeatureExtractor, self).__init__()
        vgg19_model = vgg19(pretrained=True)
        vgg19_model.features[0] = nn.Conv2d(1, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.feature_extractor = nn.Sequential(*list(vgg19_model.features.children())[:18])

    def forward(self, img):
        return self.feature_extractor(img)


class ResidualBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_features):
        super(ResidualBlock, self).__init__()
        self.conv_block = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_features, in_features, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(in_features),
            nn.PReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(in_features, in_features, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.InstanceNorm2d(in_features),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return x + self.conv_block(x)


class GeneratorResNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels=1, out_channels=1, n_residual_blocks=16):
        super(GeneratorResNet, self).__init__()

        # First layer
        self.conv1 = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(in_channels, 64, kernel_size=9, stride=1, padding=4), nn.PReLU())

        # Residual blocks
        res_blocks = []
        for _ in range(n_residual_blocks):
            res_blocks.append(ResidualBlock(64))
        self.res_blocks = nn.Sequential(*res_blocks)

        # Second conv layer post residual blocks
        self.conv2 = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1), nn.InstanceNorm2d(64))
        


        # Upsampling layers
        upsampling = []
        for out_features in range(2):
            upsampling += [
                # nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2),
                nn.Conv2d(64, 256, 3, 1, 1),  # Change output channels to 256*4      nn.Conv2d(64, 256, 3, 1, 1),
                nn.PixelShuffle(upscale_factor=2), #        nn.PixelShuffle(upscale_factor=2),
                nn.PReLU(),
            ]
        self.upsampling = nn.Sequential(*upsampling)

        # Final output layer
        self.conv3 = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(64, out_channels, kernel_size=9, stride=1, padding=4), nn.Tanh())


    def forward(self, x):
        out1 = self.conv1(x)
        out = self.res_blocks(out1)
        out2 = self.conv2(out)
        out = torch.add(out1, out2)
        out = self.upsampling(out)
        out = self.conv3(out)
        return out


class Discriminator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_shape):
        super(Discriminator, self).__init__()
        self.input_shape = input_shape
        in_channels, in_height, in_width = self.input_shape
        self.output_shape = (1, int(in_height / (2 ** 6)), int(in_width / (2 ** 6)))

        
        def discriminator_block(in_filters, out_filters, first_block=False):
            layers = []
            layers.append(nn.Conv2d(in_filters, out_filters, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1))
            if not first_block:
                layers.append(nn.BatchNorm2d(out_filters))
            layers.append(nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True))
            layers.append(nn.Conv2d(out_filters, out_filters, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1))
            layers.append(nn.BatchNorm2d(out_filters))
            layers.append(nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True))
            return layers

        layers = []
        in_filters = in_channels
        for i, out_filters in enumerate([64, 64, 128, 256, 256, 512]):
            layers.extend(discriminator_block(in_filters, out_filters, first_block=(i == 0)))
            in_filters = out_filters

        layers.append(nn.Conv2d(out_filters, 1, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1))

        self.model = nn.Sequential(*layers)

    def forward(self, img):
        return self.model(img)


# Initialize generator and discriminator
generator = GeneratorResNet()
discriminator = Discriminator(input_shape=(channels, *hr_shape))
feature_extractor = FeatureExtractor()

# Set feature extractor to inference mode
feature_extractor.eval()

# Losses
criterion_GAN = torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()  # Changed from MSELoss to BCEWithLogitsLoss
criterion_content = torch.nn.L1Loss()

if cuda:
    generator = generator.cuda()
    discriminator = discriminator.cuda()
    feature_extractor = feature_extractor.cuda()
    criterion_GAN = criterion_GAN.cuda()
    criterion_content = criterion_content.cuda()

# Load pretrained models
if load_pretrained_models:
    generator.load_state_dict(torch.load("/kaggle/working/saved_models/generator3.pth"))
    discriminator.load_state_dict(torch.load("/kaggle/working/saved_models/discriminator3.pth"))

# Optimizers
optimizer_G = torch.optim.Adam(generator.parameters(), lr=0.0004, betas=(b1, b2))
optimizer_D = torch.optim.Adam(discriminator.parameters(), lr=0.0001, betas=(b1, b2))

Tensor = torch.cuda.FloatTensor if cuda else torch.Tensor

# Fit
train_gen_losses, train_disc_losses, train_counter = [], [], []
test_gen_losses, test_disc_losses = [], []
test_counter = [idx*len(train_dataloader.dataset) for idx in range(1, n_epochs+1)]

for epoch in range(n_epochs):
    ### Training
    gen_loss, disc_loss = 0, 0
    psnr_values = []  # List to store PSNR values
    ssim_values = []  # List to store SSIM values
    tqdm_bar = tqdm(train_dataloader, desc=f'Training Epoch {epoch} ', total=int(len(train_dataloader)))
    for batch_idx, imgs in enumerate(tqdm_bar):
        generator.train(); discriminator.train()
        # Configure model input
        imgs_lr = Variable(imgs["lr"].type(Tensor))
        imgs_hr = Variable(imgs["hr"].type(Tensor))
        # Adversarial ground truths
        valid = Variable(Tensor(np.ones((imgs_lr.size(0), *discriminator.output_shape))), requires_grad=False)
        fake = Variable(Tensor(np.zeros((imgs_lr.size(0), *discriminator.output_shape))), requires_grad=False)
        
        ### Train Generator
        optimizer_G.zero_grad()
        # Generate a high resolution image from low resolution input
        gen_hr = generator(imgs_lr)
        # Adversarial loss
        loss_GAN = criterion_GAN(discriminator(gen_hr), valid)
        # Content loss
        gen_features = feature_extractor(gen_hr)
        real_features = feature_extractor(imgs_hr)
        loss_content = criterion_content(gen_features, real_features.detach())
        # Total loss
        loss_G = loss_content + 1e-3 * loss_GAN
        loss_G.backward()
        
        # Apply gradient clipping
        torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(generator.parameters(), max_norm=1.0)
        
        optimizer_G.step()

        ### Train Discriminator
        optimizer_D.zero_grad()
        # Loss of real and fake images
        loss_real = criterion_GAN(discriminator(imgs_hr), valid)
        loss_fake = criterion_GAN(discriminator(gen_hr.detach()), fake)
        # Total loss
        loss_D = (loss_real + loss_fake) / 2
        loss_D.backward()
        
        # Apply gradient clipping
        torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(discriminator.parameters(), max_norm=1.0)
        
        optimizer_D.step()

        gen_loss += loss_G.item()
        train_gen_losses.append(loss_G.item())
        disc_loss += loss_D.item()
        train_disc_losses.append(loss_D.item())
        train_counter.append(batch_idx*batch_size + imgs_lr.size(0) + epoch*len(train_dataloader.dataset))
        tqdm_bar.set_postfix(gen_loss=gen_loss/(batch_idx+1), disc_loss=disc_loss/(batch_idx+1))

        
    print(f"Epoch [{epoch+1}/{n_epochs}]")
    print(f"Training - Generator Loss: {gen_loss/len(train_dataloader):.4f}, Discriminator Loss: {disc_loss/len(train_dataloader):.4f}")

    # Testing
    gen_loss, disc_loss = 0, 0
    psnr_values = []  # List to store PSNR values
    ssim_values = []  # List to store SSIM values
    tqdm_bar = tqdm(test_dataloader, desc=f'Testing Epoch {epoch} ', total=int(len(test_dataloader)))
    for batch_idx, imgs in enumerate(tqdm_bar):
        generator.eval(); discriminator.eval()
        # Configure model input
        imgs_lr = Variable(imgs["lr"].type(Tensor))
        imgs_hr = Variable(imgs["hr"].type(Tensor))
        # Adversarial ground truths
        valid = Variable(Tensor(np.ones((imgs_lr.size(0), *discriminator.output_shape))), requires_grad=False)
        fake = Variable(Tensor(np.zeros((imgs_lr.size(0), *discriminator.output_shape))), requires_grad=False)
        
        ### Eval Generator
        # Generate a high resolution image from low resolution input
        gen_hr = generator(imgs_lr)
        
        for i in range(imgs_hr.size(0)):
            gen_hr_numpy = gen_hr[i].permute(1, 2, 0).detach().cpu().numpy()
            gt_hr_numpy = imgs_hr[i].permute(1, 2, 0).detach().cpu().numpy()
            gen_hr_numpy = np.squeeze(gen_hr_numpy)
            gt_hr_numpy = np.squeeze(gt_hr_numpy)
#             print(f"Generated image shape: {gen_hr_numpy.shape}")
#             print(f"Ground truth image shape: {gt_hr_numpy.shape}")
        
            gen_hr_numpy = (gen_hr_numpy * 255).astype(np.uint8)  # Scale to [0, 255] range
            gt_hr_numpy = (gt_hr_numpy * 255).astype(np.uint8)  # Scale to [0, 255] range

            psnr_values.append(peak_signal_noise_ratio(gt_hr_numpy, gen_hr_numpy))
            ssim_values.append(structural_similarity(gt_hr_numpy, gen_hr_numpy, multichannel=False))

        # Adversarial loss
        loss_GAN = criterion_GAN(discriminator(gen_hr), valid)
        # Content loss
        gen_features = feature_extractor(gen_hr)
        real_features = feature_extractor(imgs_hr)
        loss_content = criterion_content(gen_features, real_features.detach())
        # Total loss
        loss_G = loss_content + 1e-3 * loss_GAN

        ### Eval Discriminator
        # Loss of real and fake images
        loss_real = criterion_GAN(discriminator(imgs_hr), valid)
        loss_fake = criterion_GAN(discriminator(gen_hr.detach()), fake)
        # Total loss
        loss_D = (loss_real + loss_fake) / 2

        gen_loss += loss_G.item()
        disc_loss += loss_D.item()
        tqdm_bar.set_postfix(gen_loss=gen_loss/(batch_idx+1), disc_loss=disc_loss/(batch_idx+1))
        
        # Save image grid with upsampled inputs and SRGAN outputs
        if random.uniform(0,1)<0.1:
            imgs_lr = nn.functional.interpolate(imgs_lr, scale_factor=4)
            imgs_hr = make_grid(imgs_hr, nrow=1, normalize=True)
            gen_hr = make_grid(gen_hr, nrow=1, normalize=True)
            imgs_lr = make_grid(imgs_lr, nrow=1, normalize=True)
            img_grid = torch.cat((imgs_hr, imgs_lr, gen_hr), -1)
            save_image(img_grid, f"images3/epoch_{epoch}_batch_{batch_idx}.png", normalize=False)

    test_gen_losses.append(gen_loss/len(test_dataloader))
    test_disc_losses.append(disc_loss/len(test_dataloader))
    avg_psnr = sum(psnr_values) / len(psnr_values)
    avg_ssim = sum(ssim_values) / len(ssim_values)

    print(f"Testing - Generator Loss: {gen_loss/len(test_dataloader):.4f}, Discriminator Loss: {disc_loss/len(test_dataloader):.4f}")
    print(f"Average PSNR: {avg_psnr:.4f}, Average SSIM: {avg_ssim:.4f}")
    print("--------------------")
    
    # Save model checkpoints
    if np.argmin(test_gen_losses) == len(test_gen_losses)-1:
        torch.save(generator.state_dict(), "saved_models/generator4.pth")
        torch.save(discriminator.state_dict(), "saved_models/discriminator4.pth")

